# Concurrently running two never ending loops in python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing, speech-recognition

I'm very new to python and hope the python experts would be able to help me.
I have a program with a while loop in which I'm using speech recognition, in the same time I need to run a another loop in parallel to send keepalive signals to another device.

```
import speech_recognition as speech_recognition

speech_recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
speech_microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()

def listen_to_command():
    with speech_microphone as source:

        print("Say something...")
        try:
            run_voice_precessing(source)
        except speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError:
            run_voice_precessing(source)

def run_voice_precessing(source):
    try:
        audio = speech_recognizer.listen(source, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=10)
      
        text = speech_recognizer.recognize_google(audio)

        return text
    except handle_error//

//the loop i want to run in parallel

def check_command_timeout():
    global last_command_time
    while True:
        if time.time() - last_command_time > command_timeout :
            print("Command timeout reached. Keeping the drone alive.")
            // send the command to the device
            last_command_time = time.time()

def run_device_control():


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        text = listen_to_command()
        run_device_control(text)
```

I've tried using threads, but it doesn't seem to do the job, once the loop starts, it totally ignores the main thread and takes over the process.
I've tried running it in 2 threads, but there is a rosource issue
I've tried running concurrent processes usuing asyncio, but still if one process take a long time to finish the timeout still hangs.

```
async def run_device_control():
    while True:
        text = listen_to_command()
        run_device_control(text)
        # if this takes a long time to execute  check_timeout waits unitl this finishes
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def check_timeout():
    global last_command_time
    global time_since_last_time_out
    global init_position
    last_time_out = time.time()
    while True:
        print("---------------------------------------------------------- ")
        print("Keep alive : ", time.time() - last_time_out)
        print("---------------------------------------------------------- ")
        last_time_out = time.time()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(run_drone_control(), check_timeout())
```

I tried multiprocessing too

```
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=check_timeout())

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```

this doesn't even start the process1

What else can I try? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Right now your `while True` is  not blocking and eating 100% of the CPU (although python will give other threads time slices). Is there a reason why you can't just `time.sleep(command_timeout)`? Is something else also setting `last_command_time`?

Comment: yes, depending on the output of the speech_recognition I am executing some functions (mostly vision algorithms, which take a bit of time).  And the users might not give commands at regular intervals. @tdelaney

Comment: don't call the function when you pass it as `target` to `Process` (get rid of the extra parenthesis; `... target=check_timeout)`) in doing so, you're calling the function in the main process and the return value will be assigned to target rather than the function itself.